# How to convert SSL Certificate for mobile app?

Tags: tls, mobile, certificate-authority, websites

I am in the current process of renewing my SSL cert for my website. I also have a mobile app for my site. I want to use the same cert from my website in my mobile app. How can I do this?

Thanks - I appreciate all feedback

Comment: Which type of SSL certificate do you currently have?

Comment: DER enconded binary x.509

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to use certificate pinning to ensure you app only trusts your certificate, as opposed to anything signed by any CA. In that case, what platform are you writing the app for? Which libraries and frameworks are you using?

Comment: I am using a CA certificate [Digicert] - i want to use the same certificate that my website will use for my mobile app. My app is mainly for android and the app is written in Java

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm what you're actually asking here;

Is it that you have two domain names IE;

1 - Networkguys001-website.co.uk

2 - Networkguys001-mobileapp.co.uk

and you want to have 1 certificate which secures both domains?

If this is the case then what type of certificate did you buy from Digicert, I've included a list below;

WildCard SSL Certificates,
UC (SAN) Certificate,
Extended Validation SSL,
SSL Plus Certificate.

Typically you'd could buy a wildcard which covers; *.Networkguy.com

1 - www.Networkguy.com <- Website

2 - Mobile.Networkguy.com <-URL for Mobile

However it depends how your current domains are structured and if they're hard coded and distributed already.

Anyhow if you answer the questions I'm sure a mobile